# Tailwind: space-*-* classes messing up my whole design?

Tags: tailwind-css

I've created a very basic grid system with boxes, but when I add spacing between these columns x and y it messes up the entire design and makes it look awful?

Example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/9YYAgzmasH

By awful I mean its adding a second line to the first item out of nowhere, messing up the alignment with the rest of the boxes heights, and it seems to have messed up the width now with 2 and 3rd items being less wide than the first?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`space`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#class-reference) class, try using [`gap`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) class.

Final code:

```html
<div class="p-12 bg-blue-600 h-screen">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-y-10 gap-x-6">
        <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded shadow">
            <h1>Item 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded shadow">
            <h1>Item 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded shadow">
            <h1>Item 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/DLyorUqxh9)

Comment: This is the correct approach to use when working with Tailwind grid utilities. This is pretty clearly described in the docs here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#limitations